# Merging 2 or more data frames and transposing the result

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation, transpose

I have several DFs derived from a Panda binning process using the below code;

```py
df2 = df.resample(rule=timedelta(milliseconds=250))[('diffA')].mean().dropna() 
df3 = df.resample(rule=timedelta(milliseconds=250))[('diffB')].mean().dropna()
```

.. etc

Every DF will have column containing 'time' in Datetime format( example:2019-11-22 13:18:00.000 ) and second column containing a number (i.e. 0.06 ). Different DFs will have different 'time' bins. I am trying to concatenate all DFs into one , where certain elements of the resulting DF may contain 'NaN'.
The Datetime format of the DFs give an error when using;

method 1) `df4=pd.merge(df2,df3,left_on='time',right_on='time')`

method 2) `pd.pivot_table(df2, values = 'diffA', index=['time'], columns = 'time').reset_index()`

When DFs have been combined , I also want to transpose the resulting DF, where:

Rows: are 'DiffA','DiffB'..etc
Columns: are time bins accordingly.

Have tried the transpose() method with individual DFs, just to try, but getting an error as my time /index is in 'Datetime' format..

Once that is in place, I am looking for a method to extract rows from the resulting transposed DF as individual data series.

Please advise how I can achieve the above with some guidance, appreciate any feedback ! thank you so much for your help.

Data frames ( 2  - for example )

```
time                     DiffA
2019-11-25 08:18:01.250 0.06
2019-11-25 08:18:01.500 0.05
2019-11-25 08:18:01.750 0.04
2019-11-25 08:18:02.000 0
2019-11-25 08:18:02.250 0.22
2019-11-25 08:18:02.500 0.06
```

```
time                        DiffB
2019-11-26 08:18:01.250    0.2
2019-11-27 08:18:01.500    0.05
2019-11-25 08:18:01.000    0.6
2019-11-25 08:18:02.000    0.01
2019-11-25 08:18:02.250    0.8
2019-11-25 08:18:02.500    0.5
```

resulting merged DF should be as follows ( text only);

```
time ( first row )   
2019-11-25 08:18:01.000,     
2019-11-25 08:18:01.250,     
2019-11-25 08:18:01.500,     
2019-11-25 08:18:01.750,     
2019-11-25 08:18:02.000,     
2019-11-25 08:18:02.250,     
2019-11-25 08:18:02.500,     
2019-11-26 08:18:01.250,     
2019-11-27 08:18:01.500
```

(second row)

```
diffA   nan 0.06    0.05    0.04    0   0.22    0.06    nan nan
```

(third row)

```
diffB   0.6 nan nan nan 0.01    0.8 0.5 0.2 0.05
```

Comment: @sergiomahi, thanks for editing! much appreciated ,friend.

Comment: can you give us a sense of the data you are looking at and the expected results as an example?

Comment: @davidbilla; Absolutely, added.

Comment: Don't post your data in the form of a picture. It'll be really difficult for anyone trying to help you. It would be better if you add your data as a text, rather than as an image

Comment: @Junkrat, apologies, corrected right away, included text instead. Thank  you.

Comment: @vkd86 I would suggest you to have the image as well as the text. The image was more effective in showing your expected output. In case, you are providing text, please format the text as a code-block by using tripple-back-ticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

**The core logic**: You need to use **outer-join** on the column `'time'` to `merge` each of the sampled-dataframes together to achieve your objective. Finally resetting the index to the column *time* completes the solution.

I will use the dummy data I created below to create a reproducible solution.

> **Note**: I have used `df` as the final dataframe and `df0` as the original dataframe. My `df0` is your `df`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, column_name in zip(range(5), column_names):
    if i==0:
        df = df0.sample(n=10, random_state=i).rename(columns={'data': f'df{column_name}'})
    else:
        df_other = df0.sample(n=10, random_state=i).rename(columns={'data': f'df{column_name}'})
        df = pd.merge(df, df_other, on='time', how='outer')

print(df.set_index('time').T)
```

**Output**:

[image]

### Dummy Data

```py
import pandas as pd

# dummy data:
df0 = pd.DataFrame()
df0['time'] = pd.date_range(start='2020-02-01', periods=15, freq='D')
df0['data'] = np.random.randint(0, high=9, size=15)
print(df0)
```

Output:

```
         time  data
0  2020-02-01     6
1  2020-02-02     1
2  2020-02-03     7
3  2020-02-04     0
4  2020-02-05     8
5  2020-02-06     8
6  2020-02-07     1
7  2020-02-08     6
8  2020-02-09     2
9  2020-02-10     6
10 2020-02-11     8
11 2020-02-12     3
12 2020-02-13     0
13 2020-02-14     1
14 2020-02-15     0
```

Comment: @vkd86 Please let me know if this helped.

Comment: thanks so much for your prompt response! I have added more info after you answer.

Comment: @All,actually, df_merged3 = pd.merge(df2,df3, on='time', how='outer').fillna(nan_value), worked just fine! I can even transpose accordingly, all good! :)